# Automating the formating of all sqwiggled words in a google doc?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to automate the formating of all sqwiggled words in a google doc?

If a word contains a typo, Google doc will underline the words with a red sqwiggly line.

It there a way to programmatically format all the sqwiggled words in a document (to bold format or underlined format _for example)?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality from Google Docs for spellcheck is very limited.

It only gives you a couple of options to customize it. There is no API for spell checking from Google that could be used for the Docs and use that as a reference or to create a trigger so it can make some changes.

You can automatically change certain words by using them from Google Docs to replace words, it can be found under:

- Tools > Preferences

I think it is a great idea that could be implemented in the future, to specifically use the feature that finds misspelled words and allows you to change it to a specific word with specific formats.

You can share the idea over the community:

- For Docs/Sheets/Slides: You can send feedback from the Help menu > Report a Problem.
- Or by requesting feature under the developers form [Request Feature](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/support)

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for your feedback. :-)